# mysql: build dynamic alias from table name

Tags: mysql

is it possible to build the alias for a column dynamically from the table name?

for example:

```
Table test with Columns:
Column c1, Column c2, Column c3, Column c4

Statement: SELECT t.* AS abc FROM test AS t 
should return the values with column names: t.c1, t.c2, t.c3, t.c4
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  You can select t.* from test t -- you cannot alias more than 1 column as abc though.  Is that your question?

Comment: Yes, thats my question. I want to alias more than 1 column.

Comment: You cannot alias a group of columns with a single alias -- not sure why you'd want to.  If you post more examples and what you're trying to achieve, then perhaps we can help come up with a solution.  You can alias each individual column: Select t.c1 as abc1, t.c2 as abc2... for example.

Comment: I just wanted to save some time ;-) Now I wrote an alias for each row by hand. Thanks for your help.